# Why expect statement in bash can't use ssh-keygen command?

Tags: bash, passwords, expect

I spawn a ssh-keygen command ,and expect some output ,send `enter` ,it is right logic in the following bash script.

```
#! /bin/bash
ip="xxxx"
port="yyyy"
pass="zzzz"
cd  $HOME/.ssh
    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
    spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
    expect  "(empty for no passphrase):"
    send  "\r"
    expect  "Enter same passphrase again:"
    send  "\r"
EOF
```

No error info when to execute the bash script,why no file created in my `.ssh` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `expect` here at all. If you don't want a passphrase, use `-N ""`. (`~/.ssh/id_rsa` is also the default location for a new key, so the `-f` option isn't really necessary, either.)

```
#! /bin/bash
ip="xxxx"
port="yyyy"
pass="zzzz"

#cd  $HOME/.ssh
#    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
#    spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
#    expect  "(empty for no passphrase):"
#    send  "\r"
#    expect  "Enter same passphrase again:"
#    send  "\r"
#EOF

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "$HOME"/.ssh/id_rsa -N ""
```